# How do i remove the background from this image, just want the lettuce from the picture?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image, edge-detection

[image: image of lettuce]

Just want to retain the lettuce, I have hundreds of image like this and would be comparing the size of lettuce, so to began with I tried the canny edge detection but it doesn't seems to work, any idea how shall move ahead with this

Comment: can you post more sample images, like 5, just purely from this image, i think you can isolate the lettuce based on some custom intensity thresholding from the rgb channels.

Comment: @teng all images are nearly same just the size of the leafs will increase, that too very minor increase in size.  here's the google drive link you can have a look on sample images, https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HcaxCCKHEYSe4geIj5PjUiH6nf_AHsZZ

Comment: Why do you think that a **edge** detecting algorythm would be any good at removing the lettuce from all those balls? there are so many edges in your image - that does not seem like a good idea. ...   USe color thresholding - your lettuce is **green** the rest - rather not. the blue has probably some green in it - but marginally less then the lettuce...

Comment: Beside that .... SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not implementing your ideas. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Show what you tried and what did not work and we might be able to help you improve it - but dont use an edge detector for a color thresholding task ....

Comment: I would probably go with @PatrickArtner's approach, perhaps this is a good place to start: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html

Comment: this is a helpful tutorial https://plantcv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vis_tutorial

Comment: hey thanks @PatrickArtner, I tried the color thresholding and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the RGB image into HSV image and segment the Green color region.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

frame=cv2.imread('a.png')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower = np.array([50,50,50])
upper = np.array([70,255,255])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)

cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
cv2.imshow('res',res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: The final output]

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach is by using the Graph Segmentation method (cv::ximgproc::segmentation::GraphSegmentation), that you apply to the image converted to HSV or HSL, where you set the V or L plane to a constant to flatten illumination.

Comment: up voted for the illumination flattening suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You may get away with thresholding as long as you fix your lighting (method 1 listed below), if not, you might need a simple classifier method (for example a clustering technique, method 2) in conjunction with connected components and assumption on the location of the plant or color to assign the detected class to the plant.

```
from scipy.misc import imread
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

# read the image
img = imread('9v5wv.png')

# show the image
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.imshow(img)
ax.grid('off')

# show the r,g,b channels separately.
for n,d in enumerate([('r',0),('g',1),('b',2)]):
  k,v = d
  plt.figure(n)
  plt.subplot(131)
  plt.imshow(arr[:,:,v],cmap='gray')
  plt.grid('off')
  plt.title(k)
  plt.subplot(133)
  _=plt.hist(arr[:,:,v].ravel(),bins=100)


# method 1, rgb thresholding will not work when lighting changes
arr = img

r_filter = lambda x: x[:,:,0] < 100
g_filter = lambda x: x[:,:,1] > 80
b_filter = lambda x: x[:,:,2] < 200
mask=np.logical_and(np.logical_and(r_filter(arr),g_filter(arr)),b_filter(arr))


plt.imshow(mask,cmap='gray')
plt.grid('off')
```

[image]

```
# method 2, kmeans clustering
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
arr = matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv(img[:,:,0:3])
# ignore v per Yves Daoust
data = np.array(arr[:,:,0:2])
x,y,z = data.shape
X = np.reshape(data,(x*y,z))
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=6, random_state=420).fit(X)
mask = np.reshape(kmeans.labels_,(x,y,))

plt.imshow(mask==0,cmap='gray')
plt.grid('off')
```

[image]